# Save id from URL to USER.REQ without refreshing the page

Tags: express, fetch, ejs

I have been working on creating a Campground rating express app. So far things look really good. I’ve got full CRUD functionality on adding campgrounds, deleting them, adding reviews, authentication etc.

I’m using ejs templating to display the different campgrounds from my MongoDB.

So here’s the issue. I wanted to add an add-to-favorite button that would push the current camping id. (found in de URL) to the current user (req.user), WITHOUT refreshing the page. I’ve managed to do this the normal way by refreshing the page through a normal express request:

```
app.post("/home/:id/favorites", async (req, res) => {

  const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id);
  const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
  ;
  const campgroundstring = JSON.stringify(campground.id);
  console.log("CAMPGROUNDID=" +campgroundstring)
  
if (!user.favorites.includes(campground.id)){


 

 user.favorites.push(campground.id);
 user.save();
 console.log("campground added");

}

else{
  var index = user.favorites.indexOf(campground.id);

  console.log(index)

await user.favorites.splice(index, 1);
 await  user.save();



  console.log("this campground is deleted from favorites")
}

 


   res.redirect(`/home/${campground.id}`)
        
       console.log("REQ>USER>FAVORITES= " + user.favorites[0] + " " + user.favorites[1]);
      }
     
)
```

I understood that if you want to update data in your database you need AJAX. I tried using Fetch() but I can’t seem to understand how to extract the camping.id from the URL in the JS file with fetch and then posting the body data to my express API (How do I even create a proper API for that?) and then save it to my req.user in the Database without refreshing the page. Is this even possible?

I just can’t seem to find out how to make express, ejs and fetch() work together in this way. It’s been really frustrating and I’m really desperate for some help.Please let me know if my question is clear enough. Help is much appreciated.

Thank you,

Roland

Comment: is there any data named `id` in campground? I think if the `find` query matches any document, that will return an `_id` not `id`